# Trouble with Transpose and Repeat formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need some help with a formula I wrote in Google Sheets. 
I wanted to make a table that repeats a column of 34 locations (listed vertically) 22 times (22 items in the CountA(B3:B25) list. I expect 34*22=748 entries. But I'm seeing 722 entries. Furthermore, I counted the number of items in the list. I'm seeing only 1 F4 entry, 22 entries for F5 to F35. For F36 and F37, I'm getting 136 and 153 entries respectively!! I don't know why or what's going on. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the formula?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT((REPT(JOIN("!",SPLIT(REPT($F$4:$F$37&"!",1),"!"))),COUNTA(B3:B25))),"!")))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I get a parentheses error with your formula, so I think you may have transcribed it incorrectly.  And doesn't your inner SPLIT(REPT($F$4:$F$37&"!",1,"!") just return the F4:F37 array, with no change?  And when I guessed at removing the extra parentheses in your formula, I get an overlap of the repeating F4 values, with the last value from the range, in F37.  That is why you only get one F4 value, the initial one.  Sharing a sample sheet that has the problem, should let us find the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  SPLIT(
    REPT(
      JOIN(
        "♥",
        $F$4:$F$37,
      ) & "♥"
    ),
    COUNTA(B3:B25)
  ),
  "♥"
)
```

Or better:

```
=FLATTEN(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B3:B25)),
      TRANSPOSE($F$4:$F$37)
    )
  )
)
```